# Pandas: create dataframe with column headers and cell values from tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a simple pandas dataframe, with two columns:

```
document  document_topics 
0         [(0, 0.0280), (1, 0.0372), (2, 0.0131), ... (42, 0.0969)]
1 ...     [(1, 0.0829), (3, 0.0161), (4, 0.0141), ... (27, 0.2275)]
```

The column 'document_topics' is a tuple of (topic, weight). I would like to split 'document_topics' and get a dataframe like:

```
document  topic_0  topic_1  topic_2 topic_3 topic_4...
0         0.0280   0.0372   0.0131  NaN     NaN  
1 ...     NaN      0.0829   NaN     0.0161  0.0141
```

Not every document has all topics associated with it, so I would like to fill those values in with 'NaN'. What is the best way to create this dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

You can `explode` the lists, then grab the first and second element of the tuples and `pivot`.

```
df = df.explode('document_topics') 

df = (df.assign(topic=df.document_topics.str[0], 
                vals=df.document_topics.str[1])
        .pivot(index='document', columns='topic', values='vals'))

# Clean up names, add prefixes
df = df.add_prefix('topic_').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

---

```
   document  topic_0  topic_1  topic_2  topic_3  topic_4  topic_27  topic_42
0         0    0.028   0.0372   0.0131      NaN      NaN       NaN    0.0969
1         1      NaN   0.0829      NaN   0.0161   0.0141    0.2275       NaN
```

Comment: how did I not know about `explode`. That is rad.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know how many topics you have in total `total_topics`, then create a new list of list, each element in that list is a list which always have `total_topics` element and None if it's missing.

```
document_topics = df.document_topics.to_list()
topics = sum(document_topics, [])
topics = set([topic[0] for topic in topics])
for i, document_topic in enumerate(document_topics):
    document_topic = dict(document_topic)
    document_topics[i] = []
    for topic in topics:
        document_topics[i].append(document_topic[topic] if topic in document_topic else None)
columns = [f'topic_{i}' for i in topics]
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=document_topics, columns=columns)
```

Comment: This solution worked very well in resolving my issue since my columns were of type 'object'. Thank you!

Comment: Hope it could be your "Answer" tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform and define your own function

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['document_topics'])
df.loc[len(df), df.columns[0]] = [(0, 0.0280),
                                (1, 0.0372), (2, 0.0131), (3, 0.0969)]

df.loc[len(df), df.columns[0]] = [(0, 0.0280), (1, 0.0280),
                            (2, 0.0372), (3, 0.0131), (42, 0.0969)]


def fun(row):
    df = pd.DataFrame(row, columns=['idx', 'vals'])
    df['idx_index'] = 'topic_' + df['idx'].astype(str)
    df.set_index('idx_index', inplace=True)
    return df['vals']


df.document_topics.transform(fun)

# topic_0   topic_1 topic_2 topic_3 topic_42
# 0 0.028   0.0372  0.0131  0.0969  NaN
# 1 0.028   0.0280  0.0372  0.0131  0.0969
```